# Add a selection of methods to an instance of a pre-defined class in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, metaprogramming

For context, I'm trying to handle mouse events on instances of `Collection` from `matplotlib`. `matplotlib` handles the mouse events too, the problem is that I'm doing this from `networkx`, which uses `matplotlib.pyplot.scatter` to plot nodes on a graph. I'm not modifying `matplotlib` itself, because I don't think these features would be useful to `matplotlib`.

I also want to be able to pick and choose which events are handled and allow users to choose what happens when a mouse event is detected. So, for example, if I want something to be draggable, I would allow it to handle mouse click, motion and unclick events. However, if I want it to just give me information about a node, it just needs to handle the mouse click event.

`matplotlib` does have an example [here](http://matplotlib.org/users/event_handling.html#draggable-rectangle-exercise), where they wrap the instance in a `Draggable` class, connect to the mouse events and have functions to handle behaviour. In my case, I wouldn't know which events I would want to handle or I might not implement the callback functions for each event.

As I see it at the moment, one option is to create methods that could be bound to the instance:

```python
import types
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def on_click(self, mouse_click_event):
    '''callback on click event, mouse_click_event is passed
    automatically by mpl_connect'''
    pass

node_collection = plt.scatter(...) # Has a lot of arguments, returns a PathCollection
node_collection.on_click = types.MethodType(on_click, node_collection)
node_collection.figure.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',
                                          node_collection.on_click)
```

I think it would be relatively easy to make a series of functions that could connect the mouse events to the collection and add bound methods for the callbacks without everything clashing.

Is there a better way to be doing this? I've read up about class decorators, metaclasses and abstract base classes, but I don't think they are appropriate for my particular problem. Is there something else I haven't heard of (or more likely something that I have heard of and didn't figure to use...)?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to do monkey-patching]. Maybe this (http://stackoverflow.com/a/2375443/289011) will help?

Comment: Yes, could very well be. I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545982/monkey-patching-a-class-in-another-module-in-python) as well, which seems relevant. I'm off to bed, so will look in the morning. :)