# Python: Monkeypatching a method of an object

Tags: python, python-decorators, monkeypatching

I'm hitting an API in python through requests' Session class. I'm making GET & POST method call using requests.Session().

On every call(GET/POST) failure, I want to notify another process. I can do this by creating a utility method as follows:

```
s = request.Session()
def post():
    try:
        s.post(URL,data,headers)
    except:
        notify_another_process()
```

And call this method instead of `requests.Session().post` directly.

But, I want to monkeypatch this code to `requests.Session().post` and want the additional functionality of notifying the other process in the `requests.Session().post` method call itself. How can I achieve this?

**EDIT 1 :**

requests.Session()'s post method has the following signature:

```
def post(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
```

If I somehow try to make my a custom post like the following:

```
def post_new(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        s.post(url,data, json,kwargs)
    except:
        notify_another_process()
```

and do a patch as follows:

```
requests.post = post_new
```

This isn't really a good monkeypatching because I'm not using `self` but `session's object` inside `session.post`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does one monkey patch a function in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2375403/how-does-one-monkey-patch-a-function-in-python)

Comment: [Requests `post` method signature is different than one you've posted](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/api.py#L99)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski I'm trying to use [sessions post method](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/blob/master/requests/sessions.py#L513).

Comment: @PankajSinghal do why your code snippets does not mention creating `Session()` at all? Learn more on creating [MCVE].

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski Sorry for creating confusion. I've updated the question. Thanks for correcting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer which worked for me. It is inspired by the answers mentioned by [Siddharth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2648166/siddharth-gupta) & [lafferc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2154798/lafferc) both. This is on top of what both of them mentioned.

```
>>> import requests
>>> def post(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
...     try:
...         raise Exception()
...     except:
...         print "notifying another process"
... 
>>> setattr(requests.Session, 'post_old', requests.Session.post)
>>> setattr(requests.Session, 'post', post)
>>> s = requests.Session()
>>> s.post("url")
notifying another process
```

Answer (score 2):

This should resolve this. You basically save the old function with different name and give your function as the default post.

```
setattr(requests, 'old_post', requests.post)

def post(url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        requests.old_post(url, data, json, kwargs)
    except:
        notify_another_process()

setattr(requests, 'post', post)
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I missed mentioning about Session. Also, though your answer would be correct in case of requests but I'm going to post the answer which worked for me for the sake of clarity of the question & it's answer for the future audience(if it helps anybody in future). Thanks for answering. :)

Answer (score 2):

You're almost there, but you should use the self argument

```
def post_new(self, url, data=None, json=None, **kwargs):
    try:
        return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    except:
        notify_another_process()
```

Then set the post function to post_new

```
requests.post = post_new
```

Comment: I've updated the question. I missed mentioning about Session. Also, though your answer would be correct in case of requests but I'm going to post the answer which worked for me for the sake of clarity of the question & it's answer for the future audience(if it helps anybody in future).

Comment: Thanks for answering. :)