# Decorating requests module calls with pre and post method calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I have a class called `Client` which uses the `requests` module to interact with a service. It has methods like:

```
def get_resource(self, url, headers):
    response = requests.get(url, headers, auth=self.auth)
    return response
```

Now I want to call some methods before and after each call to the requests module. Something like:

```
def get_resource(self, url, headers):
    self.add_request_header(headers)
    response = requests.get(url, headers, auth=self.auth)
    self.process_response_headers()
    return response
```

I'm having trouble finding a way to do this without having to rewrite all `Client` methods. The most straightforward way is to change the calls to the request module to calls to self and add the calls to the methods there.

```
def get_resource(self, url, headers):
    response = self.__get(url, headers, auth=self.auth)
    return response

def __get(self, headers, auth):
    self.add_request_header(headers)
    response = requests.get(url, headers, auth=self.auth)
    self.process_response_headers()
    return response
```

But this requires me to change all the call sites and duplicate functionality of the request module. I've tried to use decorators to add these method calls to the request module functions, but got stuck with how to pass in self to the decorator.

I'm sure there's an elegant way to do this in Python.

Comment: Could you show your attempt in using decorator as you said you got stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You can use monkey patching.
read this : [Python: Monkeypatching a method of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39850270/python-monkeypatching-a-method-of-an-object)

```
    import requests
    def get(self, url, params=None, **kwargs):
        self.add_request_header(self.headers)
        response = requests.get(url, self.headers, auth=self.auth)
        self.process_response_headers()
    setattr(requests.Session, 'get', requests.Session.get)
    s = requests.Session()
```

Comment: I think the problem with this is that self refers to the Session object, while `add_request_header` is a method on `Client`

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case decorators will not be as good as it sounds and OOP is a better approach to your problem. You could use a base class Client:

```
class Client(object):
    def __init__(self, auth):
        self.auth = auth

    def add_request_header(self, headers):
        pass

    def process_response_headers(self):
        pass

    def get_resource(self, url, headers):
        self.add_request_header(headers)
        response = requests.get(url, headers, auth=self.auth)
        self.process_response_headers()
        return response
```

And create another subclasses with other implementations of `add_request_header` and/or `process_response_headers` so later you just need to instantiate the class that better suites your case

Comment: How is this different from the solution I gave in the question to which I was looking for an alternative?

Comment: @MvdD It seems I am not understanding your problem correctly, could you give two examples of `add_request_header` and `process_response_headers`?