# How do I check if pandas import is modin or original

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask, modin

While doing some OLS regressions, I discovered that `statsmodels.api.add_constant()` does the following:

```
if _is_using_pandas(data, None) or _is_recarray(data):
    from statsmodels.tsa.tsatools import add_trend
    return add_trend(data, trend='c', prepend=prepend, has_constant=has_constant)
```

If not, it treats `data` as an ndarray and so you lose some contextual information (e.g. the column names which are the regressor variables names). When importing pandas from modin, the `is_using_pandas()` above returns `False`.

It is possible that `statsmodels` need to add `modin` as a supported option to their `_is_using_pandas()` but for now, I'd like to do something like:

```
if is_using_modin_pandas(x):
    from statsmodels.tsa.tsatools import add_trend
    X = add_trend(x, trend='c', prepend=True, has_constant='skip')
else:
    X = sm.add_constant(x)
```

How would one write `is_using_modin_pandas()`?

Comment: You could try to monkey patch the `_is_using_pandas` method?

Comment: @IainShelvington@IainShelvington I've moved away from using patching some time ago but if I remember correctly, when monkey patching, you have to patch it in every module you use it because the patch changes? So to have a generic `is_using_modin_pandas()` I'll also possibly need to examine the stack to generate the patch string?

Comment: You just need to import the module where the function is defined and then overwrite that name in the module with your new function. `from foo import bar; bar.function_to_patch = my_new_function`. Since `sys.modules` is cached and is where every module is imported from, when you overwrite it once it should be overwritten everywhere

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2375443/548562